# In mako template: call python function within html string

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

How do I do this in mako:

```
<% import cherrypy %>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cherrypy.url('/media/layout.css')}" type="text/css" />

AttributeError: 'Undefined' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Comment: Have you tried importing something else, eg math?
>>> t = Template('<%import math%>Result: ${math.sqrt(9)}')
>>> t.render()
'Result: 3.0'

Comment: I got it: you need `<%! ... %>`

Comment: @atomocopter how about you write that solution as a proper answer, then tauran can accept it and later users do not have to look through comments to find the solution (and you earn something in the process) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: Instead of `<% import cherrypy %>` one needs `<%! import cherrypy %>`